# How to fill Xamarin.Forms view with equal sized bound children

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wish to bind a collection of children to a view so that the children expand to (vertically) fill the view, equally sharing the vertical space.

I can do it using a StackLayout but can't bind a collection of children.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">One</Label>
    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">Two</Label>
    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">Three</Label>
</StackLayout>
```

I can do it with a ListView but the children are stacked at the top and not expanded evenly to fill the ListView.

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
<ListView 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}" />
```

I'm overlooking something, right?

Comment: I wrote plugin for this problem. Dynamic Grid it can equal bounds of childrens and splits automatically layout per children view. I think very useful for you. You can find [**here**](https://github.com/TufanOzdemir/Xamarin.CustomViews/blob/master/Xamarin.CustomViews/Xamarin.CustomViews/Views/DynamicGridView.cs)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Grid?

```
  <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">One</Label>
      <Label Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">Two</Label>
      <Label Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">Three</Label> 
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I need to bind to the collection of children.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to bind a collection of children to a view so that the children expand to (vertically) fill the view.

**One solution:** If in **ListView** ,to do this can use **Grid** Layout as follow:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="{Binding RowHeight}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5" WidthRequest="240" HeightRequest="120">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="240" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Location}"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                    FontAttributes="Italic" 
                    VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" 
                    Text="{Binding Details}"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                    FontAttributes="Italic" 
                    VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Adding Grid to `ListView.ItemTemplate` ,here is [Creating an Inline DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-an-inline-datatemplate)
.

[image]

**Two solution:** From **Xamarin.Forms 4.0-pre1** , you also can using **[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#define-item-appearance)** to do with Grid:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                            Span="1" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        OutlineColor="Black"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                            <Grid Padding="5" WidthRequest="240" HeightRequest="{Binding RowHeight}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="240" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                            Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" 
                            Text="{Binding Location}"
                            LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                            FontAttributes="Italic" 
                            VerticalOptions="End" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" 
                            Text="{Binding Details}"
                            LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                            FontAttributes="Italic" 
                            VerticalOptions="End" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
If you want not special Height, you can binding RowHeight from Modle to Control,I have updated annswer.Modle code as follow:

```
 public double RowHeight { set; get; }
 RowHeight = (Application.Current.MainPage.Width -BarHeight - StatusBarHeight) / ItemsCount;
 // example RowHeight = (Application.Current.MainPage.Height - 44 - 20 ) /2
```

Comment: You are explicitly setting the height of children. I wish to evenly distribute the available space between the children, so if there are two children (for example) each take 50% of the available height.

Comment: @fractor Okey, height may not be explicitly setted.You also can {Binding Height}.The premise is that you can get the screen height of different devices.And when you get items count,you can calculate what height should be setted.

Comment: @fractor I have updated answer .If be helpful , remember to mark it! Thanks in advance.